# Unicode Web Scraping

Tags: python, unicode, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping item id from barney website, I am having problem in removing unicode from my output. For example, I want to get the item id as 503777359, but the output what am getting for item id is [u '503777359']. I want the output to be like this:- 503777359. What should I do?

d3 contains: "Fairfax navy and white Glenn plaid cotton poplin dress shirt.Spread collar, single-button barrel cuffs, shoulder yoke and vertical darting at back, shirttail hem, mother-of-pearl buttonsAvailable in Navy/WhiteCottonMachine washMade in JapanOur model is 6'1"/185cm and is wearing a size 15.5.
                Style # 503777359"

```
    d2=item.find("div",{"class":"panel-body standard-p"})
    d3=d2.text
    print d3
    p_id = re.findall(r'[0-9]{9}',d3)
    print p_id
```

Comment: where's the output or what is in `d3`?

Comment: sorry for that, check now. I edited my question!

Comment: can you also post the link from where you are scraping please?

Comment: link:- http://www.barneys.com/fairfax-glenn-plaid-dress-shirt-503777359.html

Comment: A few questions: Is there a listing page that led you to this URL? From where did you get the URL you're using? Is there a long list of URLs on which your code will run? Is the Product ID that's in the URL not useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just dump your [list] result into a variable like this:

```
d2=item.find("div",{"class":"panel-body standard-p"})
d3=d2.text
print d3
p_id = re.findall(r'[0-9]{9}',d3)
idICareAbout = p_id[0]
```

Of course, you could get the same source and look for

```
"<meta property="product:retailer_part_no" content="503777359" />"
```

to get the ID with only one result.

Hope this helps!

Comment: one more question:- if i need to concatenate this p_id[0] like i have shown below..what should i do? in place of p= (the 9digit numbers) , i have to concatenate this p_id @ClaFarge

Comment: Remove any of the quotes and greater-thans so i can see what you commented... I bet we can figure it out ;)

Comment: if you search for p=503777359 in that link itself, I just want to replace that whole part(the id) after "p=" with the output which I get i.e, idICareAbout.

Comment: url= "http://recs.richrelevance.com/rrserver/p13n_generated.js?a=dbeab3c977a08905&ts=1434386243747&p=503777359&pt=%7Citem_page.rr1%7Citem_page.featured_item_0%7Citem_page.featured_item_1%7Citem_page.featured_item_2%7Citem_page.featured_item_3&u=mVBBR9wkG1PJ7zehLfmNXwzRp4WGMeDLG4M%3D&s=mVBBR9wkG1PJ7zehLfmNXwzRp4WGMeDLG4M%3D&cts=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.barneys.com&chi=%7Cmens-shirts-dress-classic&flv=18.0.0&rcs=eF4NyjEOgCAMBdCFybs0obQfyg28BhRIHNzU88v68sJxf881TDUSq6hYTimWomRGm9gkh9fPZo21olN3qbT3ogUYOcATzpgRP7a2EmY&l=1"

Comment: oldStr = "p=503777359&blah"
newStr = oldStr.replace("503777359", "503NEW359")

Comment: I just want to make it a general thing for my whole code. As in, if I get a certain idICareAbout, it should get automatically concatenated with the url in the next line of my code.

Comment: If not a Replacement for another value, just append it to a string using +

Comment: I did that, i don't know why the output is not coming as expected.

Comment: please give me an example.

Comment: i have written a code to extract all recommended item id's given a particular item id no. For that it requires just to replace the particular id number with the number after *p=* to get the expected output

Comment: Using the Comments doesn;t allow me to see what you're sending me... but this will definately help to get you there: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/concatenation/string-concatenation-and-formatting-in-python

Comment: you can now see what I am asking you in the answer section below. I have pasted the url in which *p=* value has to be changed for ever idICareAbout value.

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK if the string doesn't contain weird characters a.k.a code point 128 or greater, it can be easily converted into ascii with str(). It is not unicode scraping. You are printing the content of the list. For example,

```
p_id=[u'503777359']

print p_id

[u'503777359']

p_id=[str(u'503777359')]

print p_id

['503777359']
```

As you see, "u" magically disappeared.